# Paypal IPN outstanding payments

Tags: paypal, profile, paypal-ipn, recurring, nvp

A member on site paid through CC, the IPN shows transaction type as recurring payments skipped, and the profile was later CANCELLED (profile status) by PAYPAL as documented in the docs.. and the amount is added in the outstanding amount, Now the money is not received at my end, nor there had been refund to the member, I have tried using BillOutstandingAmount API call, but it returns that the profile must be either activated or suspended, tried changing profile status with ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API call, the amount is deducted from the member CC.. what can be done in such a situation..

Comment: You said: " tried changing profile status with ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API call, the amount is deducted from the member CC.. what can be done in such a situation.." 
Did that work? You may need to have the buyer update their funding source or may continue to fail when you attempt to rebill it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that doesn't work, it shows error that profile should be either 'ACTIVE' or 'SUSPENDED'.. The current situation is the money already deducted from the BUYER's bank, the paypal IPN logs says the respective amount in 'OUTSTANDING', the profile status is 'CANCELLED'